# Is it possible to use filter in selection type in Primefaces Datatable

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to use filter in selection type in Primefaces Datatable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350812, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828754 might be helpful to you.

Comment: Using google is another option